# .NET 6.0 Stop Swagger from opening automatically on startup

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

When I run my .Net6.0 web api project in Visual Studio, Swagger UI opens automatically in a new chrome browser. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

.Net 6 integrate Swagger in the template. If you want to not auto open a tab in your browser, then you can comment `"launchBrowser": true`. If you want to auto open a tab in your browser but not the swagger UI page, then you can comment the variable `"launchUrl": "swagger"`, then a new tab will open automatically and direct to the home url like `https://localhost:7280` in my test example.

Open your `launchSettings.json` file and comment all variables `"launchBrowser": true`. In my screenshot below, since I didn't start my api app with IIS express, so I didn't comment this variable in `IIS Express`.

[image]